# Check history of the git pulls made on a local repository from a remote branch

Tags: linux, git, github

Is there a way we can view the history of the pulls that were made on a local repository?

We use a shared system and wanted to have a log of the pulls that would have been made by different users. I have searched for this on the net, but no significant luck. Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 4):

To log the pulls made on a local repository:

Every time you pull or merge a set of commits, git will make a merge commit. Therefore, this will work:

```
$ git log --merges
```

To find out which users have pulled from a Github repository:

`$ # Wait a minute, this is impossible.`

However, if you host the repository on one of your own servers, you can set up an http server with authentication, which you can then use to log the access, or With SSH access, you can configure SSHD to log which SSH key was used to access user 'git' (or whichever user your git repo is under)

Maybe you mean pull requests?

If so, use the github API to retrieve a list of open and closed pull requests: http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

Comment: However, note it's entirely possible that commits that match `Merge` in their commit message may not have had anything to do with a user running `git pull`, so this might/will over-report... I think a better answer is "`git` doesn't log pushes/pulls, and asking for data that doesn't exist is not likely to lead to satisfactory results". You probably could use one or more of the `git` hooks to gather such data, though, if it's really important...

Comment: Update: just found out about `git log --merges`. Good point about the hooks, although each user would have to install the hooks.

Comment: I think the reason why this is so difficult is that git designed to be distributed, not necessarily centralized, for use with large open source projects (linux itself.). The way users will share code with eachother in such a case will be peer to peer, based on whose fork will be most suitable for forking and working on. In that situation, logging is impossible and undesirable. What you can do is make the assumption that no-one will pull from any of your users' own repositories, and adapt the server you're hosting the central repo on to log all the pulls.